# How to read files in Android Assets

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception, adt

I have a problem with Android. I want to open file, check it and just return a simple value.

```
public void setMessageCode(String code){
        try {
            messageCode = setMsg(code);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String setMsg(String messageCode) throws IOException{
        String FILE = "src/dialogs.txt", msg;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILE)); //IO Exception here
        msg = in.readLine();
        while(msg!=null){
            message = msg.split(",");
            for(int i=0; i<message.length; i++)
                if(message[i].equals(messageCode)){
                    in.close();
                    return message[i++];
                }
            msg = in.readLine();
        }
        in.close();
        return "Nothing to get";
    }
```

So Eclipse don`t see the problem and work perfect. ADT failed. Dialogs.txt is in src/... and I checked this milion of times. What to do?

Comment: Sounds like the path/file is not right.  When you move to ADT your program is moved to the ADT file space.  You must move any files that your program uses to the correct place.

Comment: No, the problem is that assets are not actual files on the device, but merely file-like objects with an only partially similar API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I handled the problem. I passed localization of the file from activity by using getAssets("fileName") and than used it in my class in InputStreamReader. Now it looks like this.

```
public void setMessageCode(InputStream location, String code){
    try {
        messagee = setMsg(location, code);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String setMsg(InputStream location, String messageCode) throws IOException{
    String FILE = "assets/a.txt", msg;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(location));
    msg = in.readLine();
    while(msg!=null){
        message = msg.split(",");
        for(int i=0; i<message.length; i++)
            if(message[i].equals(messageCode)){
                in.close();
                return message[i+1];
            }
        msg = in.readLine();
    }
    in.close();
    return "Nothing to get";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            String first_line = read_file("dialogs.txt");
            System.out.print(first_line);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public String read_file(String filename) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                getAssets().open(filename)));

        int i=0;
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            if(++i==1)
                return line;//only read the first line
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        reader.close();
        return "Nothing to get";
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, this is good one. I done the same, but I needed it outside the activity class, so I just passed the value of (InputStream)getAsstes(). Thanks for reply!

Comment: Your welcome, :)

Most of the time I would rather to create a helper class with static values so they will be available everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Can you open the File System form Window>View while running your project and navigate to your install path to see if you have the file there.

If you want to read your file from and don't need to change it, then use assets. It you want to write into your files then you need to save it on your device which it also requires you to have proper permissions for read and write on you phone of sd-card.

Also check your file if it exists on your device before using it.

Comment: I need to read from file only. So I moved file to assets. I also changed the path to the file and the problem still exists.